# How to get Context Menu click event for a sub menu item

Tags: c#, winforms, onclick, contextmenu

I have the following code, which creates a context menu, with a sub menu;

```
ContextMenuStrip oContextMenuStrip = new ContextMenuStrip();
ToolStripSeparator oToolStripSeparator = new ToolStripSeparator();
ToolStripMenuItem oToolStripItem = new ToolStripMenuItem();

oToolStripItem.Text = "Change Status";

oToolStripItem.DropDownItems.Add("Booked", 1);
oToolStripItem.DropDownItems.Add("Pending", 2);
oToolStripItem.DropDownItems.Add("Cancelled", 3);

oContextMenuStrip.Items.Add(oToolStripItem);
oContextMenuStrip.Items.Add(oToolStripSeparator);

oContextMenuStrip.ItemClicked += new ToolStripItemClickedEventHandler(ContextMenuClick_ItemClicked);

void ContextMenuClick_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
{
    ToolStripItem oToolStripItem = e.ClickedItem;

}
```

The problem I have is the event ContextMenuClick_ItemClicked is only called when the user clicks on the Change Status menu.  What event do I need to that I can capture the click event of the item like 'Booked'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use another version of the ToolStripItemCollection.Add Method:

```
public ToolStripItem Add(
    string text,
    Image image,
    EventHandler onClick
)
```

[ToolStripItemCollection.Add Method (String, Image, EventHandler)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160942%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

For example:

```
oToolStripItem.DropDownItems.Add("Booked", null, (s, e) => BookedClicked());
```

And then:

```
private void BookedClicked() {
  // Do your magic
}
```

Comment: Can the ToolStripItemCollection.Add method take a object as well ?

Comment: Yes, it can take a ToolStripItem:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bxdt0s8t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx